# Changing user's display name on facebook

Tags: java, facebook, playframework

I want to edit user's display name on facebook through facebook api call in playframework.can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their graphapi for users http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

This is not possible.

Comment: yes, fetching it but not changing it : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me